# How to get averages of values of map of list using Streams?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a hashmap `Map<String,List<Double>> incomeList` with `String` key and `List` of `Double` as values, holding this data:

```
seattle [50000.0 40000.0 30000.0]
sanFrancisco [60000.0 100000.0]
```

i want to store city and its average income in new `HashMap` so that the final result be like this :

```
seattle 40000.0
sanFrancisco 80000.0
```

I am using this code to create this map:

```
Map<String,Double> avarage = incomeList.entrySet().stream()
         .map(e -> e.getValue().stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).average())
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

but I am getting this error:

**non static method  cannot be referenced from a static context**

Does anyone have a clue how I can get this to work using `Stream`s?

Comment: What does the stream hold after the `map`? Not `Entry` instances, therefore `Entry::getKey` and `Entry::getValue` don't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should map the original value (the `List<Double>`) into the average when collecting it into the output `Map`:

```
Map<String,Double> avarage = 
    incomeList.entrySet()
              .stream()
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                        e-> e.getValue()
                                             .stream()
                                             .mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue)
                                             .average()
                                             .getAsDouble()));
```